# Turn off "Missing Argument" warning

Tags: php

I tend to get a lot of these in PHP:

```
Missing argument 2 for ui_alert()
```

I understand how to "fix it", but thats not what I want. What I want is to change my error reporting settings so that these don't show up.

I like having my error reporting as broad as possible, but to me this warning seems ridiculous. I would have to change my entire code base every time I update a function to handle a certain use case. Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't introduce any security issues either way.

Can I surpress this specific warning without turning off any other warnings?

Comment: error_reporting(0);
[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Just fix your code. It is their for a reason!

Comment: That'll turn off additional warnings, right?

Comment: @AakilFernandes you do not want to turn off error reporting during the development process of your application.. The arguments are setup for a reason... If it's a user_defined code, then why have it accept more arguments if you only want to use one?

Comment: Turns of all error reporting

Comment: @Ed Heal, what is the reason?

Comment: The person that wrote the interpreter is more educated about the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a default value to your argument in the `ui_alert()` function declaration, like `null`, and that warning will go away.

> Can I surpress this specific warning without turning off any other
>   warnings?

No. You can turn off all warnings

There's an error control operator (`@`) that allows you to suppress any errors or warnings for an expression, but that's a bad practice and it would require you to change "the entire code base"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing your error reporting, try parsing `null` data through.. see my example below:

```
function User_Defined ($Argument_1, $Argument_2, $Argument_3){
 // Perform some functionality 
}
```

Then call your function like so:

```
    $I_Want_This_Only = 1; // Added, for the personal hate to spot obvious errors within my code. Without this, it will generate an undefined index. This is a personal preference. 
  User_Defined($I_Want_This_Only,null,null);
```

---

You can go over each of your function calls and suppress the message.. Working example:

```
function User_Defined ($Argument_1, $Argument_2, $Argument_3){
 // Perform some functionality 
}

    $I_Want_This_Only = 1; // Added, for the personal hate to spot obvious errors within my code. Without this, it will generate an undefined index. This is a personal preference. 
  User_Defined($I_Want_This_Only,null);
```

returns the error:

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for User_Defined()

But calling:

```
@User_Defined($I_Want_This_Only,null);
```

does not return an error.

---

In an ideal world, the functions are created to accept multiple arguments for a reason.. If these are user_defined functions, then why create them to accept more arguments than you actually want?

It's in best practice to not turn off error reporting.. You can turn off individual reporting such as:

`notice` OR `warning`

But this will turn off the entire reporting for each error message which fall under the notice or warning criteria. So you might have underlying issues that might pose a risk to your application.

---

**You have four options.**

- Fix your buggy code, the functions are made to accept arguments for
     a reason.
- Call your function by adding `null` to fill up the arguments.
- Suppress all your function calls which are generating this issue. But
  this has it's major downfalls.
- Turn off all `warning` criteria reporting all together.

Comment: This solution is not scalable. It involves updating every function call whenever I update a function.

Comment: You shouldn't be talking about scalability if your code is broke.